# MySQL query time periods and value of maximum drop vs preceding max value

Tags: mysql

1. How to write query that shows a date of maximum value drop vs its preceding max value (if there is a series of values that are lower than preceding max value and there are two or more values that are the lowest ones then the date of the first lowest value occurrence should be provided) 

   The query will be executed on **real time data** so for a particular date only values that date and all before are considered.
2. How to write a query that shows a date period between the end of series where a measured data was lower than its  maximum value that preceded it?

   This is an equivalent of a date period between last maximum data value and a following date of the value that is the same amount as previous maximum value or higher (whatever comes first).
   The query will be executed on **historical data** so all rows before and after a considered row are available.

Please See **Replicate** at the end of the question to generate the test table and an example query.

I tried to use window functions to achieve these queries but I could't build them. I only managed to get difference between current data of measurement and its closest max value that preceded it.

the test data looks this way:

```
+---------------------+------+
| date_time           | data |
+---------------------+------+
| 2017-01-02 00:00:00 |    2 |
| 2017-01-03 00:00:00 |    4 |
| 2017-01-04 00:00:00 |    1 |
| 2017-01-05 00:00:00 |    3 |
| 2017-01-06 00:00:00 |    1 |
| 2017-01-07 00:00:00 |    4 |
| 2017-01-08 00:00:00 |    5 |
| 2017-01-09 00:00:00 |   -2 |
| 2017-01-10 00:00:00 |    0 |
| 2017-01-11 00:00:00 |   -5 |
| 2017-01-12 00:00:00 |    6 |
| 2017-01-13 00:00:00 |    4 |
| 2017-01-14 00:00:00 |    6 |
+---------------------+------+
```

and this is the difference of a current data row vs prev max data I already have

```
+------------+------+----------+-----------+
| date       | data | data_max | data_diff |
+------------+------+----------+-----------+
| 2017-01-02 |    2 |        2 |      NULL |
| 2017-01-03 |    4 |        4 |      NULL |
| 2017-01-04 |    1 |        4 |        -3 |
| 2017-01-05 |    3 |        4 |        -1 |
| 2017-01-06 |    1 |        4 |        -3 |
| 2017-01-07 |    4 |        4 |      NULL |
| 2017-01-08 |    5 |        5 |      NULL |
| 2017-01-09 |   -2 |        5 |        -7 |
| 2017-01-10 |    0 |        5 |        -5 |
| 2017-01-11 |   -5 |        5 |       -10 |
| 2017-01-12 |    6 |        6 |      NULL |
| 2017-01-13 |    4 |        6 |        -2 |
| 2017-01-14 |    6 |        6 |      NULL |
+------------+------+----------+-----------+
```

This is wished result (**Question 1**):

```
+---------------+----------+
| diff_max_date | diff_max |
+---------------+----------+
| 2017-01-04    |       -3 |
| 2017-01-09    |       -7 |
| 2017-01-11    |      -10 |
| 2017-01-13    |       -2 |
+---------------+----------+
```

Please note that first entry `-3` is for the date `2017-01-04` because this is the first lowest value after its preceding max value: `4` date: `2017-01-03` therefore value: `-3` date: `2017-01-06` is ignored.

the query for question 1 works on live data that is inserted to the test table and because of that it is not looking forward for future entries. This is reason why there should be two lowest data entries value: `-7` date: `2017-01-09` and value: `-10` date: `2017-01-11` because at the date `2017-01-09` a value of `-10` date: `2017-01-11` was unknown.

Wished result (**Question 2**)

```
+----------------+--------------+---------------+----------+
| diff_date_from | diff_date_to | diff_max_date | diff_max |
+----------------+--------------+---------------+----------+
| 2017-01-04     | 2017-01-06   | 2017-01-04    |       -3 |
| 2017-01-09     | 2017-01-11   | 2017-01-11    |      -10 |
| 2017-01-13     | 2017-01-13   | 2017-01-13    |       -2 |
+----------------+--------------+---------------+----------+
```

Please note that second row is only value: `-10` date: `2017-01-11` and value: `-7` date: `2017-01-09` is ignored since it is not the lowest value and the query works on historical data so whole date range is available to it and not just a current date row with all preceding ones.

The queries do not need to be as a single query. It is possible to me to create dedicated tables for Q1 and for example use it to generate another table for Q2. Or add column of data from Q1 to test table and then generate table for Q2. But tried many times and failed.

Query (MySQL 8) to **Replicate** test data table and get calculated data_diff and data_max:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`
(
   `date_time` DATETIME UNIQUE NOT NULL,
   `data` INT NOT NULL
)
ENGINE InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `test` VALUES
('2017-01-02', 2),
('2017-01-03', 4),
('2017-01-04', 1),
('2017-01-05', 3),
('2017-01-06', 1),
('2017-01-07', 4),
('2017-01-08', 5),
('2017-01-09', -2),
('2017-01-10', 0),
('2017-01-11', -5),
('2017-01-12', 6),
('2017-01-13', 4),
('2017-01-14', 6)
;

SELECT 
    DATE(`date_time`) AS `date`,
    `data`,
    `data_max`,
    IF(`data` < `data_max`,  - (`data_max` - `data`), NULL) 
    AS `data_diff`

FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        `date_time`,
        `data`,
        MAX(`data`) OVER (ORDER BY `date_time` ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS `data_max`
    FROM
        `test`
    ) t
;
```

Perhaps you know at least how to get date ranges and can help me solving this problem by answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55250658/mysql-select-date-ranges-between-data-series-separated-with-null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect they can be optimised somewhat but these queries should give you the results you want. They share the same first 3 CTEs which generate the `diff_max` value for each `data_max`. In the first query we just then look for a change in that value (from `NULL` to a value, or a decrease in the value) in order to generate the output rows. The second query's 4th and 5th CTEs are similar to the first query, but we add a `RANK` to the `diff_max` values, so we can `JOIN` the minimum value (with it's associated date) to the `date_diff_from` and `date_diff_to` values from the 6th CTE (which is the same as my answer to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55250658/mysql-select-date-ranges-between-data-series-separated-with-null)).

**Question 1:**

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT DATE(`date_time`) AS `date`,
                    `data`,
                    MAX(`data`) OVER (ORDER BY `date_time`) AS `data_max`
             FROM `test`),
cte2 AS (SELECT `date`,
                `data`,
                `data_max`,
                CASE WHEN `data` < `data_max` THEN `data` - `data_max` END AS `data_diff`
         FROM cte),
cte3 AS (SELECT `date`, 
                MIN(`data_diff`) OVER (PARTITION BY `data_max` ORDER BY `date`) AS `diff_max`
         FROM cte2),
cte4 AS (SELECT `date`, `diff_max`, LAG(`diff_max`) OVER (ORDER BY `date`) AS `old_diff_max`
         FROM cte3)
SELECT `date`, `diff_max`
FROM cte4
WHERE `diff_max` < `old_diff_max` OR `old_diff_max` IS NULL AND `diff_max` IS NOT NULL
```

Output:

```
date        diff_max
2017-01-04  -3
2017-01-09  -7
2017-01-11  -10
2017-01-13  -2
```

**Question 2:**

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT DATE(`date_time`) AS `date`,
                    `data`,
                    MAX(`data`) OVER (ORDER BY `date_time`) AS `data_max`
             FROM `test`),
cte2 AS (SELECT `date`,
                `data`,
                `data_max`,
                CASE WHEN `data` < `data_max` THEN `data` - `data_max` END AS `data_diff`
         FROM cte),
cte3 AS (SELECT `data_max`, `date`, 
                MIN(`data_diff`) OVER (PARTITION BY `data_max` ORDER BY date) AS `diff_max`
         FROM cte2),
cte4 AS (SELECT `data_max`, `date`, `diff_max`, 
                LAG(`diff_max`) OVER (ORDER BY `date`) AS `old_diff_max`
         FROM cte3),
cte5 AS (SELECT `date`, `diff_max`, 
                RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY `data_max` ORDER BY `diff_max`) AS `diff_rank`
         FROM cte4
         WHERE `diff_max` < `old_diff_max` OR `old_diff_max` IS NULL AND `diff_max` IS NOT NULL),
cte6 AS (SELECT `data_max`, 
                MIN(CASE WHEN `data_diff` IS NOT NULL THEN date END) AS diff_date_from,
                MAX(CASE WHEN `data_diff` IS NOT NULL THEN date END) AS diff_date_to
         FROM cte2
         GROUP BY `data_max`
         HAVING diff_date_from IS NOT NULL)
SELECT diff_date_from, diff_date_to, `date` AS diff_max_date, `diff_max`
FROM cte6
JOIN cte5 ON cte5.date BETWEEN cte6.diff_date_from AND cte6.diff_date_to
WHERE cte5.diff_rank = 1
```

Output:

```
diff_date_from  diff_date_to    diff_max_date   diff_max
2017-01-04      2017-01-06      2017-01-04      -3
2017-01-09      2017-01-11      2017-01-11      -10
2017-01-13      2017-01-13      2017-01-13      -2
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bd91a3840885ec0e7675ce6b9562e073)