# MySQL Select date ranges between data series separated with NULL

Tags: mysql, dataset, date-range

This is a part of solving a [more complex problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55249188/mysql-query-time-periods-and-value-of-maximum-drop-vs-preceding-max-value).

There is a table with data:

```
+------------+------+----------+-----------+
| date       | data | data_max | data_diff |
+------------+------+----------+-----------+
| 2017-01-02 |    2 |        2 |      NULL |
| 2017-01-03 |    4 |        4 |      NULL |
| 2017-01-04 |    1 |        4 |        -3 |
| 2017-01-05 |    3 |        4 |        -1 |
| 2017-01-06 |    1 |        4 |        -3 |
| 2017-01-07 |    4 |        4 |      NULL |
| 2017-01-08 |    5 |        5 |      NULL |
| 2017-01-09 |   -2 |        5 |        -7 |
| 2017-01-10 |    0 |        5 |        -5 |
| 2017-01-11 |   -5 |        5 |       -10 |
| 2017-01-12 |    6 |        6 |      NULL |
| 2017-01-13 |    4 |        6 |        -2 |
+------------+------+----------+-----------+
```

I want to calculate Min and Max values of `data_diff` but separately for each data subset. Each subset of data starts with NULL (but the last one may not end with NULL but with the data) I need also start and end date of each data subset that I can later use for calculating Min, Max values. I would like to get date ranges:

```
+----------------+--------------+
| diff_date_from | diff_date_to |
+----------------+--------------+
| 2017-01-04     | 2017-01-06   |
| 2017-01-09     | 2017-01-11   |
| 2017-01-13     | 2017-01-13   |
+----------------+--------------+
```

If you would like to get the example data here's a query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`
(
   `date_time` DATETIME UNIQUE NOT NULL,
   `data` INT NOT NULL
)
ENGINE InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `test` VALUES
('2017-01-02', 2),
('2017-01-03', 4),
('2017-01-04', 1),
('2017-01-05', 3),
('2017-01-06', 1),
('2017-01-07', 4),
('2017-01-08', 5),
('2017-01-09', -2),
('2017-01-10', 0),
('2017-01-11', -5),
('2017-01-12', 6),
('2017-01-13', 4)

;

SELECT 
    DATE(`date_time`) AS `date`,
    `data`,
    `data_max`,
    IF(`data` < `data_max`,  - (`data_max` - `data`), NULL) 
    AS `data_diff`

FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        `date_time`,
        `data`,
        MAX(`data`) OVER (ORDER BY `date_time` ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS `data_max`
    FROM
        `test`
    ) t
;
```

Is it possible to write a single query that will provide date ranges as above? Or there must be a procedure or some sort of trick applied?

Maybe a window function with OVER could help but I'm not aware how to specify its window boundary between current row that is not NULL and preceding rows starting from a row preceded by NULL. Is this feasible at all?

There is `RANGE` operator for setting window boundary [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html) 
that looks promising:

> PRECEDING: For ROWS, the bound is expr rows before the current row.
>   **For RANGE**, the bound is the rows with values equal to the current row value minus expr; if the current row value is NULL, the bound is
>   the **peers** of the row.

and another part:

> ORDER BY X ASC RANGE BETWEEN 10 PRECEDING AND 10 FOLLOWING
>
> The frame starts at NULL and stops at NULL, thus includes only rows
>   with value NULL.

But I don't get the point of `inlcuding only rows with null`.
Perhaps for the date range `2017-01-02` to `2017-01-03` but for `2017-01-03` to `2017-01-07` how come?

Comment: I commend the clarity of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking at your "more complex problem" (still working on an answer) but here is a solution for this problem. Given that you are using window functions I'm assuming you're using MySQL 8 and so can use CTEs as well:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT DATE(`date_time`) AS `date`,
                    `data`,
                    MAX(`data`) OVER (ORDER BY `date_time` ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS `data_max`
             FROM `test`),
cte2 AS (SELECT `date`,
                `data`,
                `data_max`,
                CASE WHEN `data` < `data_max` THEN `data` - `data_max` END AS `data_diff`
         FROM cte)
SELECT `data_max`, 
       MIN(CASE WHEN `data_diff` IS NOT NULL THEN date END) AS diff_date_from,
       MAX(CASE WHEN `data_diff` IS NOT NULL THEN date END) AS diff_date_to
FROM cte2
GROUP BY `data_max`
HAVING diff_date_from IS NOT NULL
```

Output:

```
data_max    diff_date_from  diff_date_to
4           2017-01-04      2017-01-06
5           2017-01-09      2017-01-11
6           2017-01-13      2017-01-13
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4dd9abc49e85862ed9a354bac754c62a)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it in my crumbling, old MySQL version...

```
SELECT MIN(date_time) diff_date_from
     , MAX(date_time) diff_date_to
  FROM
     ( SELECT x.*
            , CASE WHEN @prev > data THEN @prev:=@prev ELSE @prev:= data END data_max
            , (data-@prev < 0) * (CASE WHEN data-@prev < 0  THEN @i:=@i ELSE @i:=@i+1 END) delta 
         FROM test x
            , ( SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY date_time
     ) a
 WHERE delta <> 0
 GROUP
    BY delta;
```

Comment: tested, well working alternative in case of having a MySQL not supporting CTEs and Window functions.